# In Material UI what is the difference between a space after the ampersand and no space?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

Can you please explain what is the difference between a space after the ampersand and no space

e.g.

Can you please explain why there is a space after the ampersand in & label.Mui-focused and no space in &.Mui-focused fieldset

```
const WhiteBorderTextField = styled(TextField)`
  & label.Mui-focused {
    color: white;
  }
  & .MuiOutlinedInput-root {
    &.Mui-focused fieldset {
      border-color: white;
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: To understand that you need to know first that In scss & refer to the classname itself secondly white space is used to select the classname of all that clsname ex: label.Mui-focused inside the classname whose value & is referring to. have a look to this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp

Answer (score 12):

It's the same as CSS selectors:

```html
<div class="a b">
  a and b
</div>

<div class="c">
  <div class="d">d inside c</div>
</div>

<div class="e">e</div>
<div class="f">f</div>
```

```css
.a.b {
  background-color: gold;
}

.c .d {
  background-color: blue;
}

.e, .f {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here:

- `.a.b` means an element which has class `a` AND `b`
- `.c .d` means an element with class `d` WITHIN element with class `.c`
- `.e, .f` means any element that has either `e` OR `f` as class

If you get confused how that turns into actual CSS use [JSS playground](https://cssinjs.org/repl/):

This:

```
export default {
  button: {
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        'border-color': 'white',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Will turn into:

```css
.button-0-1-13 label.Mui-focused {
  color: white;
}

.button-0-1-13 .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused fieldset {
  border-color: white;
}
```

^ Here the second selector targets a `fieldset` which appears WITHIN an element with `MuiOutlinedInput-root` AND `Mui-focused` class which is WITHIN a `button`. Something like:

```html
<div class="button-0-1-13">
  <div class="MuiOutlinedInput-root Mui-focused">
    <fieldset>
      Your fieldset here
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```